# 2d hud layer in android and opengl es

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es, canvas, orthographic

I'm trying to make an android game with opengl

I managed to set up the glOrthof view alongside the regular 3D perspective. However I'm having trouble coming up with a way to draw to the gui. I'm thinking of having one Bitmap that will be the screen, and then draw whatever I want to it with a Canvas.

I can turn the screen bitmap into a texture and map it onto a mesh which I can then render normally with the orthographic perspective.

Only problem is that I would most likely need the screen to be updated every frame, and to do that I would have to create a brand new texture whenever I want to update it. And I would imagine that to be horrendously slow.

So, how could I make a gui for my game? I have the orthographic perspective set up already alongside with my 3d perspective. The method I described above doesn't seem like it would work. Can you give me some suggestions or explain to me how I would go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS) before you start to paint the UI. This will make all drawcalls to be issued in front of the other drawcalls.